# set maximum aspect ratio with Jcrop

Tags: javascript, jcrop

How does one set a maximum aspect ratio for the image crop with Jcrop?
I've tried this but that doesn't seem to work. The crop ratio may not exeed 1/2.

```
    var options = {
        onChange: onEndCrop,
        onSelect: onEndCrop,
        minSize: [minw, minh],
        setSelect: [x1, y1, x2, y2],
        maxAspectRatio: 0.5
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you read the [Manual](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Setting_Options) you'd see that there's no such option as `maxAspectRatio`. Besides, there is `aspectRatio`. And if you'll provide it, it has to be fixed.

Comment: Then I probably looked in the wrong place, check this: https://github.com/justintv/Jcrop/commit/2959304469d0758c04a2f5a0d8843dec41109326

Comment: @PitAttack76 After analyzing the code of the whole Jcrop I came to the point that it should work, as you provided `maxAspectRatio` and did __not__ provide `aspectRatio`. There's nothing more to say, I guess. Maybe you can also review the code and make sure you have the latest version (as you pointed - the `min/maxApsectRatio` feature was added later).